# How to access folder from install web service to the main website

Tags: asp.net

In my IIS server I have a running website and a web service installed in the same website. The structure is something like this.

MainWebSite
 Folder1
 Folder2
 + WebService

Now how can I get the path of the Folder1? I want to use something like server.mapPath("Folder1")

Hope I've explained properly.

Comment: You have already answerd your own question. Server.MapPath("Folder1") will return physical path of this Folder1.

Comment: HI Gregor Primar Thanks for your comment. I also realized that after I posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Server.MapPath("Folder1")`, you cannot get out of your application root folder. If your  "Folder1" is outside root folder of webservice, then you will not be able to access this folder.

Or you may have to explain your problem a bit more.